# Safari doesn't download the file with name correctly

Tags: jsf, primefaces, safari

I've a file called "Screen Shot 2552018-09-10 at 08.17.168792378923879423789324789234789234789023478943829009872438723487990724490237842378947289379802323478923478974283923487943287937428978932478324789873924789324879034278978923478923478923470897890432879 (1).png" and my code is using command link to get it. This works fine in Chrome but in Safari doesn't. Safari changes the name of file for something in the path URL.

E.g: the url is localhost:8080/app/documents/771 so this file is renamed to 771

Safari 14

[image: Screenshot of 'show downloads' in Safari]

Chrome

[image: Screenshot of 'downloads' in Chrome]

Code

```
<h:commandLink value="#{document.fileName}" ajax="false" immediate="true"
 onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(PF('blockUIWV').show(), PF('blockUIWV').hide()); _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Documents', 'Download document,'Download']);">
 <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.downloadDocument(document.myDocument)}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

I saw that HTML5 has a download attribute so I tried to force it.

Code

```
<h:commandLink value="#{document.filename}" ajax="false" immediate="true"
 pt:download="#{document.filename}
 onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(PF('blockUIWV').show(), PF('blockUIWV').hide()); _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Documents', 'Download document,'Download']);">
 <p:fileDownload value="#{bean.downloadDocument(document.myDocument)}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

And even with this change the file wasn't with right name. But now the name is "documents" (part of my url). What's wrong in Safari and how can I fix it?

Environment

- Primefaces 6.2
- JSF 2

Comment: The obvious thing to try first is upgrade PrimeFaces to a recent version. See this commit for example: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/d6ed7620033979bd72af07b8a36cd8332395468a#diff-0f66a44d00b48c9bb601b9b3094a9c1d

Comment: @JasperdeVries Unfortunately this won't be so easy for my team bc the system is huge

Comment: @DanielaMorais I feel like Jasper is onto something with the fixes he mentioned as there were numerous bugs open about it. Looks like file names with "spaces" and "parens" in in them were a problem and your example has both.

Comment: Can you examine the content-dispositon HTTP header in Network traffic tools of Safari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after researching I think you should report this issue to Apple.

See PF ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6327

This filename works fine in Chrome, Firefox, MS Edge.  It only doesn't work in Safari.

In PF 9.0 we added a new feature AJAX File Download where it does work https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5978 and Safari downloads the file name correctly.